# Mockito implementation on queryForObject

Tags: mockito, springmockito

I'm having impl class that extends an interface havinf function to select the entries from the database-

```
public class EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
public List<Employee> getAll() {
    String query = "select id, name, role from Employee";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    List<Map<String,Object>> empRows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

    for(Map<String,Object> empRow : empRows){
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setId(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(empRow.get("id"))));
        emp.setName(String.valueOf(empRow.get("name")));
        emp.setRole(String.valueOf(empRow.get("role")));
        empList.add(emp);
    }
    return empList;
}
```

}

How can I mock it using Mockito framework?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; it helps to know the attempts you have made, tutorials you have followed, or specific problems with understanding how things work. Please add more details about your attempts or problem when asking future questions.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, this is also not a good use case for Mockito, as your only injected dependency (DataSource) needs to appear as [an entire SQL-supporting database connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). It is not practical to mock such a powerful and deep interface, especially as passed to another collaborator (JdbcTemplate).

Though you could refactor to test the translation of your `List<Map<String, Object>>` to `List<Employee>`, that may not be a particularly useful test, particularly because it doesn't involve the database or its schema at all.

Instead, I recommend using [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or another in-memory database to prepare data as you expect to see it, and then check that your `List<Employee>` comes out right. Such a test would not use Mockito at all, but would exercise all of the code you've written in a deterministic way.